# how to declare class with 1000000 elements c++

Tags: c++, class, arrays

I am writing a c++ code and my need is to declare a class having two elments as

```
class arr{
    public:
        long num;
        string str;
};
```

now i need to store almost 1000000 elments of this class(depending on user input number of class object can warry in a range of 1 <= n <= 1000000 
The object are created dynamically as

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class arr{
    public:
        long i;
        string str;
};

int main(){
    long n,j,i;
    cin>>n;
    arr a[n];
```

.... rest of programme

but if value of n is large then 100000 then programs hang but works fine for value less then 100000 what approach should i try to declare more than 100000 objects in a go i tried solving issue with help of 2D array that is dividing  arra in two part

arr a[1000][1000];

but this approach is not working for me

please if anybody have any idea do help me out with this 
thanks in advance

Comment: Don't declare big objects on the stack. As you've found, it's asking for trouble. Some old-style alternatives are to declare the objects as global static variables or allocate the objects dynamically. A more modern alternative is to use one of the standard library's container classes.

Comment: ohh thanq i just found a way out by using vector

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197933/how-to-declare-class-with-1000000-elements-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to declare class with 1000000 elements c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197933/how-to-declare-class-with-1000000-elements-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Just use std::vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    long n;
    cin>>n;
    std::vector<arr> a(n);
}
```

and my problem is solved as answer by @davic Hammen stack can not hold large array dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a class with 100,000 elements. Instead, create a class with one element that can hold multiple values -- an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the array like this instead of declaring them on the stack:

```
// Allocating memory
arr *a = new arr[n];

// Example of usage:
cout << a[x].str

// Freeing memory
delete [] a;
```