# Failed to generate disassembly for stack frame because the URL cannot be translated & Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c++, xcode, segmentation-fault, program-entry-point, exc-bad-access

I am still a newbie in programming. I am writing a program of 2D Snell's Law. I know the problem may due to wrong localisations in Xcode, but I am writing in C++ only and g++ even gives me segmentation fault error after compiling successfully.

Here are my code for main function:

```
#include <string>

#include "Snell.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){//thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=2 address=0x7fff5f238304)
    string filename;
    double time;
    Snell S[3600];

    for (int i=1; i<=1; i++) {
        while (S[i].angle_tr>0) {
            filename="VPVSMOD"+to_string(i)+".txt";
            S[i].Open(filename);
            time=S[i].Locate(i);
            cout<<"The "<<i<<"th event takes "<<time<<" seconds to reach the destination"<<endl;
            S[i].angle_tr-=0.01;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for Snell.hpp

```
#ifndef Snell_hpp
#define Snell_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Snell{
private:
    double GetV(double lat,double dep);
    int ny,nz,time;
    double la[30],h[20],v[10][30];
    double lat,alt,step;
public:
    Snell();
    void Open(string filename);
    double Locate(int i);
    double angle_tr;
};

#endif /* Snell_hpp */
```

and Snell.cpp:

```
#include "Snell.hpp"

Snell::Snell(){
    ny=1,nz=3,time=0;
    lat=0,alt=0,step=1;
    angle_tr=M_PI/2;
}

void Snell::Open(string filename){
    ifstream fin(filename);
    stringstream ss;
    string str,tok;

    for (int i=0; i<nz; i++) {
        (getline(fin, str));
        ss.str(str);
        for (int j=0; j<ny; j++) {
            getline(ss, tok, ',');
            v[i][j]=stod(tok);
            cout<<v[i][j]<<",i="<<i<<",j="<<j<<endl;
        }
        ss.clear();
    }

    fin.close();
    angle_tr=v[1][0]/v[0][0];
}

double Snell::GetV(double lat, double dep){
    int index_la = 0,index_dep = 0;

    index_dep=round(dep);
    return (v[index_dep][index_la]+v[index_dep+1][index_la])/2;
}

double Snell::Locate(int i){
    string filename;
    double count_t=0;
    double latt=lat,altt=alt,step_altt_all=0,angle=0,angle_p=0;
    double vsy,vsz;
    double vs,vs_n;
    ofstream fout;
        angle=M_PI/2-atan(angle_tr);
        vs=GetV(lat, alt);

        filename="Test"+to_string(i)+"_"+to_string(time)+".txt";
        fout.open(filename,ios::out);
        fout<<lat<<","<<alt<<endl;

        while (altt!=2) {
            //cout<<"Compute Velocity in each dimension"<<endl;
            angle_p=angle;
            vsy=vs*cos(angle);
            vsz=vs*sin(angle);
            //cout<<"Check Velocity"<<endl;
            if (vsy==0||vsz==0) {
                break;
            }

            //cout<<"Compute reflection point"<<endl;
            step_altt_all=step/vsz;
            count_t=count_t+step/vsz;//time plus one
            latt=latt+vsy*(step_altt_all);
            step_altt_all=0;
            altt=altt+step;

            //cout<<"Compute New Velocity"<<endl;    
            vs_n=GetV(latt,altt);
            if ((vs_n*cos(angle)/vs)>1) {
                break;
            }
            else{
                angle=M_PI/2-asin(vs_n*cos(angle)/vs);
                vs=vs_n;
                if (angle!=angle_p)
                    fout<</*"position:"<<*/latt<<","<<altt<<endl;
            }
        }

        fout.close();
        filename="Result"+to_string(i)+"_"+to_string(time)+".txt";
        fout.open(filename);
        fout<<0<<" "<<latt<<" "<<altt<<" "<<step<<endl;
        fout.close();
        return count_t;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate guess is: You must have blown your stack. Please see [why is stack memory size so limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482974/why-is-stack-memory-size-so-limited)

....And yes, On my platform, my guess was correct...

Reproducing your program, but modifying your `main.cpp` ...

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){//thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=2 address=0x7fff5f238304)
    string filename;
    double time;
    //Snell S[3600];
    std::cout << sizeof(Snell) << " bytes" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It gives an output of

```
2848 bytes
```

....And You are trying to allocate `3600` of them... ~`10MB`!!
The solution to that is to allocate it on the heap using a `std::unique_ptr` or better still, your **good** friend, `std::vector`.

Modify your main to this

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
//or #include <vector>

#include "Snell.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){//thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=2 address=0x7fff5f238304)
    string filename;
    double time;
    std::unique_ptr<S[]> p(new Snell[3600]);
    //or std::vector<Snell> S(3600);

    for (int i=1; i<=1; i++) {
        while (S[i].angle_tr>0) {
            filename="VPVSMOD"+to_string(i)+".txt";
            S[i].Open(filename);
            time=S[i].Locate(i);
            cout<<"The "<<i<<"th event takes "<<time<<" seconds to reach the destination"<<endl;
            S[i].angle_tr-=0.01;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your previous help. Now I have another question: Why will it crash for just 10MB size in total?