# Neo4j nested exception is: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, neo4j

In Neo4j terminal window I run the following line of code: 
**neo4j-shell -file NetworkUpdate2015.cypher**

And I receive the next Error:
**ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.StackOverflowError**

If I run the file in blocks of 5000 records did not make mistake, however I need to do in a single run. The file contains 22755 rows

Anyone can help me determine the cause of the error and if necessary modify any configuration parameter? Thanks.

Comment: increase the jvm heap size

Comment: I´m using Java for OS X 2015-001. Where can I change the heap size?

Comment: Append -Xss<size> to JVM command line to set max stack size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java stack overflow error - how to increase the stack size in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127217/java-stack-overflow-error-how-to-increase-the-stack-size-in-eclipse)

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace and the content of your cypher file

Answer (score 0):

What is the Cypher query you are executing? Is it a `LOAD CSV` script or is the file 22k lines of Cypher?

See [this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-performance.html) for steps to increase JVM heap size.

Comment: It's not a LOAD CSV. From terminal I execute the next line: **neo4j-shell -file NetworkUpdate2015.cypher**

Comment: @ReneD.Ayala: Can you share the contents of the `NetworkUpdate2015.cypher` file?