# How to increase stack size eclipse.ini file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My rcp based launcher has launcher.exe which has some recursive call during class loading so getting a stack over flow error. To avoid it I have to increasing the stack size. but unable to launch the application through launcher.exe but works fine from a windows batch script
I found similar thread [forum post about increasing stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127217/java-stack-overflow-error-how-to-increase-the-stack-size-in-eclipse)
but of not much help.
my eclipse.ini :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-Xss4m
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
-Declipse.buildId=44.1.2
```

But strangely though through a windows batch script this works perfectly fine:

```
@echo off
java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Xms256m -Xmx256m -Xss2m -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar -application xx.yy.zz.mm.application.application -showSplash splash.bmp

exit
```

Don't know why the -Xss agrument is not considered by eclipse.ini
environment : Windows7+eclipse Neon+ 64bit java1.8

xxx.product file has following entry for VM agruments:

```
<launcherArgs>
  <vmArgs>-Xms256m -Xmx2048m -Xss4m 
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
  </vmArgs>
  <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
  </vmArgsMac>
  <vmArgsWin>-Declipse.buildId=44.1.2
  </vmArgsWin>
</launcherArgs>
```

I found [oracle blog here](https://blogs.oracle.com/saas-fusion-app-performance/how-to-set-stack-size-to-overcome-javalangstackoverflowerror) so tried with -Xss4096k in ini file but of no luck yet! Don't know the difference between launching through ini and launching through the command line. looks as if both are same but surely they aren't.

Comment: For a start the application id must be on a separate line from -application and no spaces before -startup

Comment: How are you creating this file? It is normally generated by the RCP build from data in the xxx.product file. It normally has a `--launcher.library` entry and the application is specified in the `config.ini` also generated from the xxx.product file.

Comment: thanks greg-449 for the reply. actually after the ini file got generated I have changed manually to get it worked. I'll take your suggestion and now re building the application. Once builds I'll verify.

Comment: Note that you can specify the VM arguments in the xxx.product file.